# Author's own, well researched answer was deleted

Tags: discussion, moderation

[Can an ID in a lookup field ever be invalid? Anywhere?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22719/can-an-id-in-a-lookup-field-ever-be-invalid-anywhere)

Richard has put some effort into answering his own question, we provided some hints/ideas but in the end I'd say it's his own hard work.

His answer got 4 upvotes to date... and somebody flagged it for moderator's attention as "not an answer". I'd say it looks good for me. Can we have an undelete?

[image: the deleted answer]

I saw that flagged post in the review queue and the button said "flag or disagree"... although for the life of me I couldn't find option to disagree, just different reasons to flag it (spam, low quality etc).

Comment: While I'd agree he'd written this more as a "reply" than an "answer", I do agree with you that he should been warned/advised and given the opportunity to improve the quality of this answer.

Comment: I deleted the answer, as it looks more as an edit to his original question. I will undelete, and will comment that there should be some editing to the answer.

Comment: @Saariko can you post it as answer so I can accept? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I deleted the answer, as it looks more as an edit to his original question. I will undelete, and will comment that there should be some editing to the answer.

Answer (score 13):

I believe that to disagree with a flag, you have to flag it. (Yes, that does sound weird)

[image]

Comment: That's what I did with the one you've captured on the screenshot :) Takes a while to find it on the list, easy to miss.

Comment: Hmmm, that could be a lot more obvious!